# Why is it "De l' " and not "Des" in this sentence

Tags: articles, passé-composé, imparfait, articles-definis

This is an exercise from Duolingo. So the exercise asks to translate this sentence:

> **I ate pineapple everyday in Mexico.**

And the correct answer is:

> **J'ai mangé de l'ananas tous les jours au Mexique.**

There's two things that I don't understand about this sentence. First, why did we use the partitive article "de l'" instead of the indefinite articles "des" for the word "ananas". Like when we say:
Je manges *des/un* fruit.

Plus, fruit is countable so it doesn't need a partitive article.

And in case if both me and Duolingo are correct, I wonder about the difference in meaning that "des" and "de l'" would make.

Second thing I don't understand is the usage of the passé composé instead of the imparfait; as it's a past habit.

Comment: Related: [“mange du chocolat” vs “mange le chocolat”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14560/mange-du-chocolat-vs-mange-le-chocolat)

Comment: There is no *imparatif* tense and I don't think you misspelled *impératif*. Can you confirm *imparfait (de l'indicati)f* is expected here?

Comment: I've just changed it to _imparfait_ . I totally mixed the two words up.

Answer (score 3):

1. *First, why did we use the partitive article "de l'" instead of the indefinite articles "des" for the word "ananas".*

   You can use either the partitive or the indefinite articles here but it makes more sense to use the partitive if you didn't eat whole ananas but chunks / slices of them, probably the most common case. That would even be no choice for bigger stuff like *j'ai mangé du bœuf tous les jours* (I ate beef everyday) and never *j'ai mangé des bœufs tous les jours* (I ate oxen everyday) unless you are a T-Rex ;-). Moreover, the English sentence doesn't use the plural so doesn't read *I ate pineapple**s** everyday...*
2. *I don't understand is the usage of the passé composé instead of the imparfait; as it's a past habit.*

   Both the *imparfait* and the passé composé are valid French. There have been [many questions](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=imparfait%20pass%C3%A9%20compos%C3%A9) around this choice here.