# Why do some some verbs like manger need a de ?

Tags: verbes, articles, partitif

"I like to **eat** ice cream" is translated as "J'aime ***manger*** de la glace.

Comment: [La difference entre « j'aime le fromage » et « j'aime du fromage »](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/8345/1893) has an answer about the partitif.  There's more under the [partitif] tag.  It's not just the verb manger but the category of food and drink as objects of the verb.  Since I can't post a full answer right now, I hope you can look through those links.

Comment: @livresque "j'aime du fromage" is not really heard.

Comment: @Frank It is not, I agree.  The answer I linked includes manger and verbs with the partitif, not aimer.  Toto oui c'est la même question mais ça manque un peu la réponse de rems.

Comment: The *de* isn't associated with the verb *manger* but with the noun *glace*; here, *de la glace* uses the *partitive article*, meaning something like *some ice cream*. You generally need to use an article in French (although there are numerous exceptions to this rule), so you can't say **je veux manger glace* — that's ungrammatical.  You need to say *je veux manger de la glace* — *I want to eat some ice cream*.